# C: Pointer arithmetic and malloc() - NO GO?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, memory-mapped-files

Getting familiar with pointers, I came across the section of dynamic memory allocation using malloc() as well as free(). I would like to have confirmation or correction on my understanding of this topic.

Until now, I understood the big benefits of pointers to be two-fold:

1. Call by reference (i.e. variables outside a function can be accessed and altered using a pointer without the need of the variables being global).
2. Using pointer arithmetic, it is a very convenient and code-efficient way of going through an array (e.g. a char array as a string), accessing and manipulating data.

Talking about malloc(), I kind of feel that pointer arithmetic can become quite dangerous if the pointer address is not being reset. Given the example below, I created two pointers ptr and ptr1 using malloc().
I understand that the two malloc() functions allocate two memory blocks, each as big as  size*sizeof(int), so this is reserved memory and the addresses of the first elements of these two blocks are given to ptr and ptr1.

Using the first for loop, I am assigning values into the memory locations using pointers. ptr uses pointer arithmetic, ptr1 uses array arithmetic (If I can call it that way).

At the end of the for loop, ptr does not point to the address of the first element of the reserved memory block, and must be reset back in order to point to the address of the first element.

The second for loop prints the data stort in the two memory blocks. There, I do not reset ptr to point to the address of the first element in the memory.

Now the big question:
Using free(ptr), free() receives a pointer that points to a certain address (other than the start address of the memory block that was reserved). Do I understand correctly that writing free(ptr), I will now release a different memory block of size*sizeof(int) and I might release some sensitive data that should not be released?

Is that correct understood? If so, would it advisable to always use array arithmetic when using pointer in connection with malloc()?

Thank you,
Alex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int size = 0;
printf("Enter the array size: ");
scanf("%d",&size);

int * ptr = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int * ptr1 = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

int i = 0;
// First for loop
for( ; i<size;i++)
{
    *ptr = i;
    ++ptr;
    *(&ptr1[i]) = i;
}

ptr = ptr-size; // Resetting to the start address

// Second for loop
for(i = 0; i<size;i++)
{
    printf("%d\t\t",*ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("%d\n",*(&ptr1[i]));
}

free(ptr);  // Is the correct memory block now freed?
free(ptr1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code changes `ptr` and then passes an effectively random value to `free`. It is poor design trying to adjust it afterwards: keep a copy if necessary. You must pass to `free` the *exact* value that was returned by `malloc`, regardless of *which* variable holds it. There is no memory of the actual variable that was used to obtain the memory.

Comment: The rule is that you have to give to `free` the same address it returned in `malloc`, that's it. If you manipulate your pointer so that it points it somewhere else, then it's **your job** to keep track of the original address. Whether you manipulate back the pointer or you keep another one, that doesn't matter. Remember **always** give `free` the same address `malloc` gave to you.

Comment: When you are trying to understand code like this I find it helpful to step through it in a debugger and see how each line changes variables, memory, etc, it is way better than seeing a blast of printfs scroll by your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior. The pointer value passed to `free()` must be *exactly equal* to a value obtained from `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value
>   returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc()
>   (since C11).

So keep an unadulterated pointer to your allocation to pass to `free()`, and use a copy for the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there are redundant operators used in these statements

```
*(&ptr1[i]) = i;
```

and

```
printf("%d\n",*(&ptr1[i]));
```

They are equivalent to

```
ptr1[i] = i;
```

and

```
printf("%d\n", ptr1[i] );
```

If a pointer has a value that differs from the value returned by a call of malloc then calling free for such a pointer results in undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that in this loop

```
for( ; i<size;i++)
{
    *ptr = i;
    ++ptr;
    *(&ptr1[i]) = i;
}
```

you could use explicitly the pointer arithmetic for the pointer ptr like

```
for( ; i<size;i++)
{
    *( ptr + i ) = i;
    *(&ptr1[i]) = i;
}
```

In this case the value of the pointer ptr itself would not be changed.